# Assign folders privilidges for App Pool Identity (CLI Only)

Tags: windows, iis, docker, command-line-interface, access-control-list

I have a site running on IIS 10 in the default app pool.

I need to give permissions for it to read to a folder tree in a (Windows) docker container.

How, using the CLI only, can I determine what user I need to give permission to in order for them to access the folders?

I've tried:

1. `icacls "C:\inetpub\MyWebsite" /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)F`
2. `icacls "C:\inetpub\MyWebsite" /grant "IIS AppPool\MyWebsite":(OI)(CI)F`
3. `icacls "C:\inetpub\MyWebsite" /grant "ApplicationPoolIdentity
   ":(OI)(CI)F`  (Error: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.)
4. `icacls "C:\inetpub\MyWebsite" /grant "Network Service":(OI)(CI)F`
5. `icacls "C:\inetpub\MyWebsite" /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F`

Answer (score 0):

yep, do not determine what user the IIS application is running under. this is a terrible idea, you want to create secure pool not whack all under the app poll access.

**Instead do the following:**

1. create a new user on the VM
2. assign the new user to the app poll
3. give permission s to the user to  read all the directories you want to have access to from the IIS

to do the steps I would use **powershell**

```
 Import-Module WebAdministration
 Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$($pool.name) -name processModel -value @{userName="$($creds.UserName)";password="$($creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)";identitytype=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add read (not full) permissions to the IUSR account. Or tell IIS to not use IUSR for anonymous access:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'SiteName' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "userName" -value ""
```

Replace SiteName with the name of your site.